# Unable to bind Windows environment variables to Docker Compose Environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I currently have a compose file for a Windows .Net service, and I want to be able to pass through a user-space environment variable:

Set from powershell:

```
powershell [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(\"PREVIOUSLY_SET_WINDOWS_ENV_VARIABLE\", $env:computername, \"User\")
```

Docker compose file:

```yml
services:
  myservice.commandline:
    image: myservice.commandline:dev
    build:
      args:
        source: ${DOCKER_BUILD_SOURCE}
    volumes:
      - .\myservice.commandline:C:\app
      - ~\msvsmon:C:\msvsmon:ro
    entrypoint: powershell -Command [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep([System.Threading.Timeout]::Infinite)
    environment:
      - MY_VARIABLE_NAME=${PREVIOUSLY_SET_WINDOWS_ENV_VARIABLE}
    labels:
      - "com.microsoft.visualstudio.targetoperatingsystem=windows"
```

This does not work - the environment variable shows as blank.

`- MY_VARIABLE_NAME=${PREVIOUSLY_SET_WINDOWS_ENV_VARIABLE}` doesn't work.

How do I pass a windows environment variable through to a Docker Compose environment variable?

Background:

- `${PREVIOUSLY_SET_WINDOWS_ENV_VARIABLE}` doesn't work.
- `$PREVIOUSLY_SET_WINDOWS_ENV_VARIABLE` doesn't work.
- `$(PREVIOUSLY_SET_WINDOWS_ENV_VARIABLE)` doesn't work.
- `${%PREVIOUSLY_SET_WINDOWS_ENV_VARIABLE%}` doesn't work.

Comment: Before running `docker-compose up`, check if the variables exist in environment using `echo $PREVIOUSLY_SET_WINDOWS_ENV_VARIABLE`. Or You can use [env_file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file), which is more reliable and less likely to change with changing environments.

Comment: @Doug, Make sure environment did get set and also use `docker-compose config` to check what the parsed file looks like

Comment: @TarunLalwani @Ayushya I have checked both of these things. The variable is being set. I have also tried both Windows User and Machine environment variables. No luck, the value is always null. Knowing that windows references these using `%ENV_NAME%` naming, i wondered if I was referencing it incorrectly in the compose file using ${}?

Comment: Try that and without braces also.

Comment: @TarunLalwani sorry - for clarity I tried about 50 different attempts before posting. without {} doesn't work either. Neither does with ().

Comment: Is this all in a single session? I'm not sure if changes made by `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable` will be accessible until you restart the process. If it _is_ the same session, try using `$env:PREVIOUSLY_SET_WINDOWS_ENV_VARIABLE = $env:computername` instead.

Comment: This is broken regardless of sessions. Even if you set them through the windows setting pane, they aren't pulled in.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any solution to this?